# Use 2020 iMac as primary display for Mac Studio?

Tags: display, imac, screen, airplay, mac-studio

I have a mac studio without any display and a 2020 iMac. I would like to use the iMac (or even some other macbook) as the primary display for the mac studio. As far as I searched, the possible option is using either [the AirPlay or some other software](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-an-iMac-As-an-External-Monitor) which does not seem to outperform AirPlay.

But it looks like I will run into the following issues since I don't possess a normal display for mac studio in the first place.

- When I open the box of mac studio, I cannot even start it to initialize because the iMac screen will not work before setting up the mac studio properly.
- Every time I start my mac studio, I guess some setting in it is necessary before the iMac screen works, which is then not possible.

Any solutions or suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this.

The only iMacs that work with what Apple calls Target Display Mode are the 2011 to 2014 iMacs.

For reference, [this article from Apple Support.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592)

You will need to get an actual monitor.